# Whether SQL Blocking Session will be cleared by itself?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can view the blocking session in our Production DB.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.sysprocesses WHERE spid = YOURSPID
```

I have not killed the session  : `Kill  <SPID>`

Does the blocking session will get clear by itself ?

Comment: Loosely related but use `sp_whoisactive` more info and more human readable.

Comment: *"Does the blocking session will get clear by itself ?"* Not as long as the session is legitimately active.

Comment: I was told to use : beta_lockinfo. Can i see the active users from this syntax as well. Can i kill the active user who is blocking the session. I presume i would be seeing only active users..

Comment: The blocked process will wait until the blocking ends or if the situation ends up in a deadlock, then the server will choose to kill one of the processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the user(if any) who is active and who if any is executing the query. If there is any active user who has blocked the session then you have to kill the session for that user or else wait for him/his session to get finished. You can execute the `sp_whoisactive` to check the list of active users. And check if any user is blocking the session then you can explicitly kill the session for that user to get it working.

You can also refer: [Identify the cause of SQL Server blocking](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2927/identify-the-cause-of-sql-server-blocking/).

> This query is also a good way to analyze detailed information about
>   locks, and help you to identify the cause of a large number of blocks.

```
WITH [Blocking]
AS (SELECT w.[session_id]
   ,s.[original_login_name]
   ,s.[login_name]
   ,w.[wait_duration_ms]
   ,w.[wait_type]
   ,r.[status]
   ,r.[wait_resource]
   ,w.[resource_description]
   ,s.[program_name]
   ,w.[blocking_session_id]
   ,s.[host_name]
   ,r.[command]
   ,r.[percent_complete]
   ,r.[cpu_time]
   ,r.[total_elapsed_time]
   ,r.[reads]
   ,r.[writes]
   ,r.[logical_reads]
   ,r.[row_count]
   ,q.[text]
   ,q.[dbid]
   ,p.[query_plan]
   ,r.[plan_handle]
 FROM [sys].[dm_os_waiting_tasks] w
 INNER JOIN [sys].[dm_exec_sessions] s ON w.[session_id] = s.[session_id]
 INNER JOIN [sys].[dm_exec_requests] r ON s.[session_id] = r.[session_id]
 CROSS APPLY [sys].[dm_exec_sql_text](r.[plan_handle]) q
 CROSS APPLY [sys].[dm_exec_query_plan](r.[plan_handle]) p
 WHERE w.[session_id] > 50
  AND w.[wait_type] NOT IN ('DBMIRROR_DBM_EVENT'
      ,'ASYNC_NETWORK_IO'))
SELECT b.[session_id] AS [WaitingSessionID]
      ,b.[blocking_session_id] AS [BlockingSessionID]
      ,b.[login_name] AS [WaitingUserSessionLogin]
      ,s1.[login_name] AS [BlockingUserSessionLogin]
      ,b.[original_login_name] AS [WaitingUserConnectionLogin] 
      ,s1.[original_login_name] AS [BlockingSessionConnectionLogin]
      ,b.[wait_duration_ms] AS [WaitDuration]
      ,b.[wait_type] AS [WaitType]
      ,t.[request_mode] AS [WaitRequestMode]
      ,UPPER(b.[status]) AS [WaitingProcessStatus]
      ,UPPER(s1.[status]) AS [BlockingSessionStatus]
      ,b.[wait_resource] AS [WaitResource]
      ,t.[resource_type] AS [WaitResourceType]
      ,t.[resource_database_id] AS [WaitResourceDatabaseID]
      ,DB_NAME(t.[resource_database_id]) AS [WaitResourceDatabaseName]
      ,b.[resource_description] AS [WaitResourceDescription]
      ,b.[program_name] AS [WaitingSessionProgramName]
      ,s1.[program_name] AS [BlockingSessionProgramName]
      ,b.[host_name] AS [WaitingHost]
      ,s1.[host_name] AS [BlockingHost]
      ,b.[command] AS [WaitingCommandType]
      ,b.[text] AS [WaitingCommandText]
      ,b.[row_count] AS [WaitingCommandRowCount]
      ,b.[percent_complete] AS [WaitingCommandPercentComplete]
      ,b.[cpu_time] AS [WaitingCommandCPUTime]
      ,b.[total_elapsed_time] AS [WaitingCommandTotalElapsedTime]
      ,b.[reads] AS [WaitingCommandReads]
      ,b.[writes] AS [WaitingCommandWrites]
      ,b.[logical_reads] AS [WaitingCommandLogicalReads]
      ,b.[query_plan] AS [WaitingCommandQueryPlan]
      ,b.[plan_handle] AS [WaitingCommandPlanHandle]
FROM [Blocking] b
INNER JOIN [sys].[dm_exec_sessions] s1
ON b.[blocking_session_id] = s1.[session_id]
INNER JOIN [sys].[dm_tran_locks] t
ON t.[request_session_id] = b.[session_id]
WHERE t.[request_status] = 'WAIT'
GO
```

Comment: thanks. You say that there is both Active and InActive Users will be showed as result in that query execution ??

Comment: @goofyui:- Updated my answer!